# Найти тег и добавить ему определенный класс php

Tags: php

Есть строка `$this->lists['categories']`, которая содержит в себе тег `select`, в котором в свою очередь находится список категорий. Так вот этот `select` имеет следующий вид уже на странице
     `<select id="catid" name="catid">
        <option value="0" selected="selected">- Выберите категорию -</option></select>`

Ну и далее список категорий, так вот мне нужно задать `class` этому `select`. Пытаюсь через `preg_replace()` следующим образом:

```
<?php
   $arr=preg_replace("<select>", 
   "select class='selectpicker' data-live-search='true'", 
   $this->lists['categories']) 
 ?>
<?php echo $arr; ?>
```

Вроде заменяет, **но** так же заменяет атрибут `selected` (т.е. режет его на **select** и **ed**). Подскажите как этого избежать? Может есть регулярное выражение на такой случай. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Знаки, обозначающие тег (вокруг select) у вас идут как ограничители поисковой строки. Обычно используются другие символы, например "/". Т.е. должно быть так:

```
preg_replace("/<select>/", ...)
```

Но тогда этот код не сработает если есть что-то внутри тега select (id или еще что-то). Так-же надо искать только внутри тега Select, я бы предложил сделать типа такого:

```
preg_replace("/<select([^>]*)>/", "<select class='newclass' $1>", ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно "в лоб" обычным реплейсом например так:

```
str_replace('select id=', 'select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true" id=', $this->lists['categories'])
```

Comment: Автору надо дом парсить и собирать по уму, а не на абум заменять неизвестное количество селектов

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'filter_function_name_11' );

function filter_function_name_11( $content ) {
    $content = preg_replace( '/<select>/', '<select class="my-class>', $content );

return $content;
```

}

Фильтр обрабатывает функцию the_content, где после проверки страница не является главной происходит замена тэга select на тэг select (только уже с классом).

Учти: если добавить в functions.php, то этот фильтр будет работать на всех страницах, кроме главной. Если тебе нужно на определенном странице вызвать, замени проверку или вставь этот фильтр на ту страницу, где хочешь проделать эту манипуляцию с тэгом.